# Maintaining encapsulation with C-style struct access

Tags: c++, encapsulation, const-cast

Say I have a class:

```
class Foo
{
    int _bar;

    public:
        Foo (const int); //sets bar as well
        bool setBar (const int);
        int getBar(); 

        const int &bar;
};
```

This would allow for both C and C++ methods of getting the data, but still verifying valid data when setting. It could be used as follows:

```
int main()
{
    Foo foo (10);
    cout << foo.getBar(); //OK, prints 10

    foo.bar = 5; //error: bar is const
    foo._bar = 5; //error: _bar is private, use bar instead
    foo.setBar (6); //OK, foo._bar is now 6

    cout << foo.bar; //OK, prints 6
}
```

However, all is not well. This also allows for one specific dirty trick:

```
Foo foo (1000);
const_cast<int &> (foo.bar) = 5; //OK, bar's const is casted away
cout << foo.bar; //OK, prints 5
```

What happens if I don't want people abusing half the point of putting it into a class in the first place? Am I just forced to not allow for some leeway towards people who prefer just (seemingly) accessing the member directly because of one fault, or is there some trick to actually allow both the syntax (for reading) and the encapsulation?

---

The best way of preserving the syntax I can think of (with consistence this time) without using that method would be to:

```
private: 
    int _bar;
public:
    int bar() { return _bar; }
    void bar (const int data) { _bar = data; }

... 

foo.bar (5);
cout << foo.bar();
```

Would this be the ideal way of approaching it with an intent on keeping old syntax and class stability instead? The only way I can think of to maintain the syntax exactly is to have the data member wrapped in a small class, but that seems like a lot of work for each class you would apply this to.

Comment: Of course, people can subvert any mechanism with the right combination of casts.  I wouldn't worry about it; the point of `const`, access specifiers etc. is to guide people to use your interface correctly/safely.  You can't deter the truly determined from pulling tricks.

Comment: I suppose. I guess if someone screws themself over by using it, that's their problem. It's one thing if it's accidental, but going out of your way to use `const_cast` obviously isn't.

Comment: The other thing I'd say is that there's not much point having the `getBar()` function if you're allowing "direct" access via the reference as well.

Comment: It does take up space, but it's mostly there for having both C and C++ idiomatic access.

Comment: I think it boils down to what behavior you want your class to have, and also what `int _bar` is supposed to represent (without a specific case, this will probably be difficult to answer).

Comment: @Jesse, it's mostly applicable for classes in which the members are obvious, such as a `Student`: `s.name, s.grade, s.age`. I can't really think of an example to counter that logic at the moment, though.